# Suppress warn logs for exception in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a custom exception like this

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class AccessException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

But when I throw it from a @RestController, it's logging this:

```
2018-04-17 11:44:58.239  WARN 17928 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: site.user.AccessException
```

I tried checking the source code but could not find where this is getting logged. I don't want to turn off logging because it may log other things that I am interested in. I just don't think that a custom exception like this should be logged every time.

Answer (score 1):

You may set log level for class `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` to `ERROR`. That way you will only loose `WARN`, `DEBUG` and `TRACE` logs for this class only.

If there are some WARN-level exceptions you want to see from this class I see two options:

- copy `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver`  to your codebase, change the logging. Make sure that your copy is on the top of the classpath and Spring is below. This is kind of hack. ResponseStatusExceptionResolver is implementation detail of Spring. It may be changed/moved/deleted in future release.
- write your own implementation of org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver, register it, make sure that ResponseStatusExceptionResolver is not registered.

Comment: There is another warn-level logger in that same class for non-annotated exception classes that I don't want to lose.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring you can add this line into your `application.properties` to specify logging level for certain class:

```
logging.level.site.user.AccessException=ERROR
```

or

```
logging.level.site.user.AccessException=OFF
```